# Is there a way to see from all perspectives in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I watch a lot of YouTubers that show many types CSGO scene. But, I don't know how they do to see all the perspectives. I've tried by downloading one of my matches and I couldn't change my viewing angle from myself.
I want to see all the perspectives
Thanks to anyone that helps.

Comment: so you want to replay a demo and see the other players first person view?

Comment: yes, and i want the grenade camera too, but the other players camera is good enough

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

You wanted to see all perspective that is possible in the game. Well there is 2 possible answers that could come.

### Answer #1 (From replay)

Yes, you can do it if you got the replay. You can download your replay by going to the Watch tab and going to the Your Matches tab
For there, select one of the replay you wanted and load it!
You can change the viewing angle by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> button
Yes, you can go to free viewing mode by changing the viewing angle a few time until you can control yourself using <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>or <kbd>D</kbd> key

### Answer #2 (from demos)

No, you can't do it from demos since demos is only recording your screen.

Comment: You can use `<kbd>button</kbd>` to highlight keyboard buttons, maybe it's good to know ;)

Comment: Thank you @Nitro.de for telling me and also editing my post!

Comment: AFAIK demos work too but I really am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

> > The Problem
>
> You wanted to see all perspective that is possible in the game. Well
>   there is 2 possible answers that could come.
>
> Answer #1 (From replay)
>
> Yes, you can do it if you got the replay. You can download your replay
>   by going to the Watch tab and going to the Your Matches tab For there,
>   select one of the replay you wanted and load it! You can change the
>   viewing angle by pressing Space button Yes, you can go to free viewing
>   mode by changing the viewing angle a few time until you can control
>   yourself using W,A,Sor D key
>
> Answer #2 (from demos)
>
> No, you can't do it from demos since demos is only recording your
>   screen.

You are partly right,

When you finsh a match yougo into your watch tab then Right-click you get the options: GOTV, View Scoreboard and watch highlights.

**GOTV** Is the one you want you can see it from all perspectives rewind time and fast forward. P.s you can also go into free mode which lets you travel around not bound to a player.

**Scoreboard** Here you can see the scoreboard from that match (Not their ranks).

Finally,**Highlights** These are ALL of your kills and bomb defuses/plants and its good if you want to make a montage or something